# Enhanced Lookups (All Fields)

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, lookup, custom, lookup-filter

Are custom lookup fields searchable with the (All Fields) Search Enhanced Lookup on a Custom Object?

In this example:
I have a "Well" (Custom Object) record that has a look up relationship to a "Rig" custom object. If I type in the name of the Rig into an enhanced lookup on a different record it returns no results (I confirmed that the 'All Fields' selection was made) on the lookup search box.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Relationship fields (and picklist fields) are not included in the search. Though the enhanced lookup search covers more than just the name field, the search scope is still limited to searchable fields on the object, which include:

- Auto-number fields and custom fields that are set as an external ID
- Email and phone fields
- Fields of type text, text area, long text area and rich text area
- Some other fields that are dependent on the object (see [Searchable Fields by Object](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=search_fields.htm) in the help topic)

Comment: Thanks Shannon. So even if I created some type of formula field to spit out the text of the lookup relational field I am still going to run into the same problem right? Any ideas to make that relational field searchable in some way?

Comment: Formula fields aren't searched either. But if you have Enterprise Edition or higher, you might be able to use a workflow rule to copy the value from the lookup into a custom text field.

Comment: Sorry last question... Does the field have to appear on the layout in order for it to appear in the enhanced lookup search?

Comment: No. It also doesn't have to be visible to the user through FLS -- it's still going to return results.